# Countdown function with two parameters

Tags: python

I am trying to create a countdown function with two parameters, without using any built in functions other than `range` (if needed). I want to only use `loops`.

The function counts down based on the parameters given. For example, if I type `countDown(10, 2)` then it prints out a countdown from 10 and subtracts by 2 and should not print anything past the number 1. So it will look like:

```
>>>countdown(10,2)
       10
       8
       6
       4
       2
       Blastoff!
```

I know how to write a similar countdown code, without the conditions listed above, using only one parameter which is:

```
def countdown(n):
  if n == 0: 
     print "Blastoff!" 
  else: 
     print n 
     countdown(n-1)
```

But I am having trouble coding the conditions listed above with a loop with two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that just uses a simple, non-recursive loop:

```
def countdown(n, m):
    for i in range(n, 0, -m):
        print i
    print "Blastoff!"
```

#### How it works:

The python function `range` takes up to three arguments: the start value, the stop value, and the increment.  Thus, `range(n, 0, -m)` starts from `n` and counts down, stopping *before* it reaches `0`, using `-m` as the increment.  You can observe this on the python command line.  Just type `python` on the command prompt and you will see the `>>>` prompt.  Then type the command `range(10, 0, -2)` and press return:

```
>>> range(10, 0, -2)
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

After you enter the command, python returns with `[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]` which is the value returned by `range`.  It is a list of numbers.

The `for` loop runs through each value returned by `range(n, 0, -m)` and prints it.  You can see this on the command line also:

```
>>> for i in range(10, 0, -2): print i
... 
10
8
6
4
2
```

When we are done looping through the values returned by `range`, we print `Blastoff!` and the function is complete.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what your code is exactly doing? Because I would have never guessed to do that.

Comment: @Robben See updated answer.  Let me know if any questions remain.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying! Your explanation helped a lot.  I am learning day by day how to code in python.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
def countdown(n, m):
  if n <= 0: 
     print "Blastoff!" 
  else: 
     print n 
     countdown(n - m, m)   #reduce m from n and recursive call to countdown
```

Using while loop:

```
def countdown(n, m):
  while n > 0:
     print n
     n -= m

  print "Blastoff!"
```

Comment: Actually can you explain what the program is doing in `else` , `print n` and `countdown(n-m,m)`? I am having difficulty understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Recursive method with 2 parameters    
def countdown (n, step):
    if n <= 0:
        print "Blastoff!"
    else:
        print n
        countdown (n-step, step)

def main():
    countdown (10, 2)

main()
```

Comment: The answer mainly exists already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25197002/2648551).